# JavaScript fetch API template string

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, openweathermap

I'm trying to make an app that gives you the weather based on your location. I get the location with ipinfo, and it works. I put the location in a variable, and when I console log it it still works. But when I try to fetch data from openweathermap with that variable using a template string this is what the console shows:

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: currentCity is not defined
> at getWeather

The problem is when I copy that link to the console it returns a link that works!

```
const getLocation = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('http://ipinfo.io/json?token=(id given by ipinfo)')

    if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json()
        return data.city
    } else {
        throw new Error('Unable to get the current location')
    }
}

let currentCity


getLocation().then((city) => {
    currentCity = city
    document.write(currentCity)
}).catch((err) => {
    // Do something with it later
})


const getWeather = async () => {
    const response = await 
    fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${currentCity}&units=metric&id=524901&APPID=(id given by openweathermap)`);

    if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json()
        return data
    } else {
        throw new Error("Unable to get weather")
    }
}

getWeather().then((data) => {
    console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Your code needs to synchronize the flow.I have added an example for the same. Have a look over it and if that works for you upvote and accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same and if in case it doesn't, leave me a comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are two asynchronous call, one is **getLocation()** and another is **getWeather()**.

According to the current code both of them are running asynchronously, without any sequence flow defined.

What you need is to **synchronize** both of them such that **first location** is fetched **after that weather** for that location is fetched.

The below is the way you can sychronize the two methods to execute one after the other.

```js
const getLocation = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('http://ipinfo.io/json?token=(id given by ipinfo)')

  if (response.status === 200) {
    const data = await response.json()
    return data.city
  } else {
    throw new Error('Unable to get the current location')
  }
}


const getWeather = async(currentCity) => {
  const response = await
  fetch(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${currentCity}&units=metric&id=524901&APPID=(id given by openweathermap)`);

  if (response.status === 200) {
    const data = await response.json()
    return data
  } else {
    throw new Error("Unable to get weather")
  }
}



getLocation().then((city) => {
  currentCity = city;
  document.write(currentCity);
  return city;
}).then((city) => {
  return getWeather(city);
}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch((err) => {
  // Do something with it later
})
```

By chaining the promises as below it is achieved. Also modified the getWeather() method to accept location as a parameter to make it a reusable unit.

```
getLocation().then((city) => {
  currentCity = city;
  document.write(currentCity);
  return city;
}).then((city) => {
  return getWeather(city);
}).then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch((err) => {
  // Do something with it later
})
```